# Math notation for the $x$ that minimizes $f(x)$ while keeping $f(x)$ above $t$.

Tags: notation

I want to say: The $x$ that minimizes $f(x)$ while keeping $f(x)$ above $t$.

I know I can write "the $x$ that minimizes $f(x)$" like this: $x = \arg\min_x f(x)$.

How would I complete that to say "while keeping $f(x)$ above $t$"?

Comment: How about $\forall y:(t\leq f(y))\wedge (t\leq f(x)\leq f(y))$

Comment: $\arg\min_{x, f(x) > t} f(x)$

Comment: "arg" ?? ....Write $t(x)=\min \{f(y):y>t\}$ or $f(x)=\min_{y>t}f(t).$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet "$\min_x f(x)$" returns the minimum function value of $f(x)$, whereas $\operatorname*{argmin}_x f(x)$ returns the value(s) of $x$ that minimise $f(x)$ (as in the "argument" that "minimises" the function). For example, $\min_{x \in \Bbb{R}} (3 + (x - 1)^2) =  3$, but $\operatorname*{argmin}_{x \in \Bbb{R}} (3 + (x - 1)^2) =  1$ (or perhaps, technically, $\{1\}$).

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{amin}{\operatorname*{argmin}}$The best suggestion was made by lhf in the comments:
$$\amin_{\substack{x \\ f(x) > t}} f(x).$$
You could alternatively use the inverse image notation, i.e.
$$f^{-1}(t, \infty) := \{x : f(x) \in (t, \infty)\} = \{x : f(x) > t\}$$
to write
$$\amin_{x \in f^{-1}(t, \infty)} f(x).$$